# Where are the project's files configured?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

In VS 2019 for an Asp.Net Core project, where is the place where the included files and build actions are maintained?

I can't find them in the .csproj file, which is very clean compared to previous versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to see the fully expanded project as MSBuild sees it after the SDK and its targets are included, you can try the `dotnet msbuild -preprocess` command that could show which files are imported, their sources, and their contributions to the build without actually building the project.

For detailed information, please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#how-to-see-the-whole-project-as-msbuild-sees-it

Comment: Does it mean that what's included for build is based on a predefined default list of files? What does other language extensions mean in `Compile **/*.cs (or other language extensions)`? Where do .html files fall under?